# Use multiline textbox for user input rather than single line VB.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

Currently my application is working properly using two separate text boxes and the user enters one sku and one order number then clicking a button to run the SQL query. To make this app more efficient I would like to allow the user to enter a list of orders in a multiline textbox but I am not sure how to setup the variable to pass the list to my query.

Current state:

```vb
Private Sub btnCancelLines_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancelLines.Click
    MdiParent = Toolbox


    Try
        Dim orderNum As String = CStr(txtOrder.Text)
        Dim skuNum As String = CStr(txtSKU.Text)
        SQL.AddParam("@order", txtOrder.Text)
        SQL.AddParam("@SKU", txtSKU.Text)

        SQL.ExecQuery("update sop10200
                       set qtycance = qtytoinv, qtytoinv = '0', ATYALLOC = '0', QTYREMAI = '0'
                       where ITEMNMBR = @sku
                       and SOPNUMBE = @order;")
        If SQL.HasException(True) Then Exit Sub
        dgvData.DataSource = SQL.DBDT


        LoadGrid()

    Catch ex As System.InvalidCastException
        MessageBox.Show("Please use numbers",
                        "Error")
        Console.WriteLine("An error occured")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("An unknown error occured",
                        "Error")
    End Try
End Sub
```

My multiline textbox is txtOrderList obviously I would change my SQL query to an IN statement.

If someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Comment: Rather than a ,multiline TB which results in code to split, parse and match up the data into pairs, why not something like a  2 column DGV? It *might* even be possible to forego formatting it all into a query.  BTW,  what does `CStr(txtOrder.Text)` do?

Comment: I was looking at ML TB so the user can copy and paste their list in. I believe CStr(txtOrder.Text) it makes it a string. At least that was my intent.

Comment: txtOrder.Text is already a string.

Comment: Now, *that* could be an interesting question.  Wouldnt they have to post 2 lists? That would seem to mean code to match them up, which prudence would seem to call for the user 'approving' your pairings.  Then the grody SQL.  Seems much more error prone and complicated than some other things.  Text is not a data type different from string.

Comment: Use xml and build a table variable in SQL you can join to... or a delimted string you can parse and then create a table variable from it.

Comment: @Plutonix not really. What this code is doing is canceling a specified SKU off of several specified orders. So if we are out of item 1234 i need to drop it off several orders, yet keep the order intact.

Comment: @Codexer you are way over my head :)

Comment: @Mark Slagle See my post about it...

Comment: @Codexer maybe the dumbest question today, how do I get to your post about it?

Comment: My answer below on the page ... @MarkSlagle

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish this task.

1. You could build an `XML` string from your selections and then pass that into a stored procedure and then create a table variable you could join to.
2. Create a delimited string you can split inside your call that would insert into a table variable.

For Example:

```
 Dim orderNums As String = String.Join(",", txtOrder.Lines)
 SQL.AddParam("@order", orderNums)
 'Execute your query...
```

In your query...

```
 SQL.ExecQuery("DECLARE @tbl TABLE(OrderNums BIGINT);
                INSERT INTO @tbl(OrderNums)
                SELECT x.value
                FROM STRING_SPLIT(@order, ',') x;                     
                UPDATE sop
                SET qtycance = qtytoinv, qtytoinv = '0', ATYALLOC = '0', QTYREMAI = '0'
                FROM @tbl t
                INNER JOIN sop10200 sop
                  ON sop.SOPNUMBE = t.OrderNums                   
                WHERE sop.ITEMNMBR = @sku;
                ")
```

Hopefully this will get you on the right track... The above would update everything in the `sop10200` table where the order numbers were provided.

Comment: Got it (duh) Compiler is not happy with "String.Join"

 BC30518 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Join' can be called with these arguments:
    'Public Shared Overloads Function Join(separator As String, ParamArray value As String()) As String': Value of type 'String()' cannot be converted to 'String'.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the database and if you use store procedure or not, there's no easy way. You'll have to built your query with a for loop like this

```
where ITEMNMBR IN (@sku0, @sku1, ...)
```

Then add the sku

```
Dim skus = txtSKU.Text.split(",")

SQL.AddParam("@SKU0", skus(0))
SQL.AddParam("@SKU1", skus(1))
...
```

This is a quick example, you'll definitely need to use loop to built it properly.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To skus.length - 1
    SQL.AddParam("@SKU" & i, skus(i))
Next
```

Similar For loop would be needed to build the query.

Comment: With that method i would need to know how many lines they are putting in the multiline textbox wouldn't I?

Comment: Yes, after doing a split, you would know how many there are by looking at the .length property